# Scrollview is scrolling to the right

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a scrollview that is a set width. I constrained it to be the width of the parent view. When I scroll the scrollview there is a lot of space to the right. I only want it to scroll vertically not horizontally.

Can someone please help?

Here's the code

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant : 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant :0).isActive = true
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    self.scrollViewContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollViewContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    self.scrollViewContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.scrollViewContentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    self.scrollViewContentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1000).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: Also, set the width of the child equal to scrollview's width

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: @liquidLFGUKRAINE I added code. Please see.

Comment: hi @liquidLFGUKRAINE can you help me with this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440632/setting-a-view-to-have-equal-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's an issue with the width. Make sure that the scroll view's width is equal to the width of the safe area and then make the subview's (view inside the scroll view) width equal to that of scroll view.

Also check if the leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints are set as 0 and not -1 or -2.